# maximum distance between n points on unit circle

Tags: geometry, optimization, roots-of-unity

Let's n points $M_k$ on the unit circle. Find the position of these points such that $$P_n = \prod_{1 \le k \le l \le n}M_kM_l$$
(product of all the distances between the points)
is maximum.

With the Hadamard inequality, we can proove that $P_n \le n^{\frac{n}{2}}$.

If the points are the $n$-roots of unity (or the image by a rotation of the $n$-roots of unity), we can proove that the inequality is a equality.

My question :  how to proove that the $n$-root of unity are the only (modulo a rotation) configuration that realize the maximum ?

Comment: $M_k$ is a point and $M_kM_l$ is the distance between the points $M_k$ and $M_l$.